# Grafana Renderer for Panels

Tags: grafana, grafana-api, grafana-alerts

I have a Grafana setup and running locally on my machine. I wanted to try

1. Get list of all dahboards and panels inside them.
2. Use grafana-image-renderer plugin to get the PNG images of all those panels.
3. Get the JSON data used to render those panels(data source).

I am not clear on configuring the render and also on the APIs.

Comment: After a little bit of playing around, I figured out a way for 1 and 2.

1. api/search?query=% will give list of dashboards with their panels; couple it with /api/dashboards/uid/<panel-id>/ to get panel details.

2. Install image-rendere plugin and get the png from /render/d-solo/<dashboard-uid>/<dashboardname>?orgId=<>&panelId=<>

3. still trying to figure out if we can get the plot coordinates exactly.

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/search/dashboard-previews/